# Need help on lifetime issue

Tags: rust

```
pub struct Decoder<'a> {
    reader: &'a mut io::Reader+'a,
}

impl<'a> Decoder<'a> {
    pub fn from_reader(r: &'a mut io::Reader) -> Decoder<'a> {
        Decoder {
            reader: r,
        }
    }
}

// shortcut method to accept bytes to decode
pub fn decode<'a, T: Decodable<Decoder<'a>, IoError>>(data: Vec<u8>) -> DecodeResult<T> {
    let mut r = MemReader::new(data);
    let mut decoder = Decoder::from_reader(&mut r); // error: `r` does not live long enough
    Decodable::decode(&mut decoder)
}
```

I have two question here.

1. How do you read this declaration(what it means) `reader: &'a mut io::Reader+'a`. Which I was referencing the code from the [std json encoder](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/94b0aace1a1ca638bdf8b935b16dd802d6eea2f1/src/libserialize/json.rs#L387).
2. I write a shortcut method to wrap `Vec<u8>` with MemReader, so that I can just interfacing io::Reader. But the compiler complains `error:`r`does not live long`. How to make it right.

**Update:** I upload the code to [github](https://github.com/jarod/amf-rs).

Comment: Do `Decodable` and `DecodeResult` come from an existing library, or did you define them yourself? Could you add the necessary `extern crate` and `use` declarations, or their definitions (the minimum required to reproduce your error) if they're your own types, to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first `'a` means that the `Reader` object itself has lifetime `'a`. The second `'a` means that the `Reader` object doesn't *contain* references that outlive `'a`. Since `Reader` is a trait, it could be implemented by a struct that has lifetime parameters. This bound applies to those potential lifetime parameters.
2. The problem is with the bound on `T`: `Decodable<Decoder<'a>, IoError>` references the lifetime parameter `'a`. However, the `Decoder` you're creating references a local variable, whereas `'a` refers to a lifetime that lives longer than the function call (because it's an input parameter specified implicitly at the call site).

   I think there's no way to make this function compile successfully without unsafe code for the moment. In fact, [`Encoder::buffer_encode`](https://github.com/jarod/amf-rs/blob/ea532d5995492efa389bcca9da372296ff0260e4/src/amf0.rs#L47) seems to be having the same issue ([#14302](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/14302)) and uses a similar workaround. `transmute` allows us to coerce the local lifetime to `'a`.

   ```
   pub fn decode<'a, T: Decodable<Decoder<'a>, IoError>>(data: Vec<u8>) -> DecodeResult<T> {
       let mut r = MemReader::new(data);
       let mut decoder = unsafe { mem::transmute(Decoder::from_reader(&mut r)) };
       Decodable::decode(&mut decoder)
   }
   ```